# How to display the contents of <td> in two different lines in Thymeleaf and Spring Boot?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a `Spring Boot` based application that displays some data in tabular format.

I would like to display some values on two different lines but within the same `<td>`. Something like this.

```
Mule: Down
TC: Down
```

**ServerService.java**

```
public String getServerStatus(String kdn, String hostname, String serverType) {
        String muleStatus = getMuleStatus(hostname, MULE_DEV_STATUS_SSH_CMD);
        String tcStatus = getTCStatus(hostname);
        serverStatus = muleStatus + "<br/>" + tcStatus;
        return serverStatus;
  }
```

From the service class mentioned above, I changed my logic to return a `String` that looks like this: `TC: Down <br/> Mule: Down`, hoping that the browser would automatically parse this `HTML` tag 
and will display the contents on two different lines within the same column. But that didn't work.

Hence I added `<td th:text="${#strings.escapeXml(appDeploy.server.status)}">001</td>` in my `server.html` file but that also didn't help and in the browser I see something like this.

```
Mule: DOWN&lt;br/&gt;TC: DOWN
```

Not sure what else is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose just make it break to two lines in Thymeleaf, you should change th:text to th:utext.

```
<td th:text="${appDeploy.server.status}"></td>
```

Be like:

```
<td th:utext="${appDeploy.server.status}"></td>
```